# О тщетности понять значение авторского употребления слова

Tags: синтаксис, выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика, смысл

Вот выдержка из новости, в новости вещает о чём-то видный физик Ковальчук.

Михаил Ковальчук, президент Национального исследовательского центра «Курчатовский институт»: «Мы с вами живем в такое время, когда каждый наш следующий шаг нас приближает к тому, что любой продукт уклада, в котором мы уже живем, **это будет уже сублимированное знание**. И даже если мы не будем его производить, мы должны понимать, как это делается. А вообще главная цель, и, я думаю, года науки, это привлечение молодежи в науку и поднятие авторитета научного знания среди людей».

Об оборот "сублимированное знание" я просто запнулся. Что такое "сублимированное знание"? Как бы вы истолковали это словосочетание?

Comment: Если вам нужно запастись едой длительного хранения, и при этом вы не хотите сидеть на одних только консервах, то сублиматы - то, что вам нужно. К тому же они удивительно мало весят и их удобно носить с собой.

Сублиматы (сублимированные продукты) – это натуральные продукты, полуфабрикаты (например, томатная паста или плавленый сыр) и даже готовые блюда (каши, ризотто, омлет, бульон, повидло и пр.) крайне быстро обезвоженные по специальной технологии сублимированной сушки, для восстановления которых достаточно добавить воды.

Comment: Что вы хотите от сбивчивых слов попу**ляля**ризатора науки. Редактированию эта *живая речь* не подлежит. Все фразы — ляпы.

Answer (score 1):

Сублиматом называют  пищевой продукт, законсервированный методом сублимации с целью длительного хранения. Технология метода включает в себя два основных этапа: замораживание и вакуумно-сублимационную сушку. Уменьшение веса продукта за счет удаления из него воды, а так же удобство использования делает его привлекательным, например,  для туриста…

Сублимация - переход вещества из твёрдого состояния в газообразное, минуя жидкую фазу. Сублимация происходит от лат. sublimatio «возвышение; очищение», далее из sublimare «поднимать, вздымать; возвышать», далее из sublimis «высокий, возвышенный»…

В цитируемом фрагменте, обороту «сублимированное знание» можно приписать значение:
«свободное от лишних наслоений (воды и шелухи) - чистое (рафинированное) знание».
Необходимо знать и понимать технологию самых важных этапов в процессе изготовления продукта (даже если мы его не производим).

Впрочем, живую речь, изобилующую пропусками слов, бывает непросто - просто записать, а уж толковать чужую запись чужих слов - занятие вовсе неблагодарное.
Вот еще один вариант цитирования той же самой фразы: «…каждый наш следующий шаг нас приближает к тому, что любой продукт уклада, в котором мы уже живем, - это будет уже [результат применения] сублимированного знания». https://tass.ru/obschestvo/13049291?nw=1638133722000

Comment: "...понимать технологию этапов процесса изготовления продукта". 

От такого наслоения друг на друга родительных падежей пухнет голова.

Comment: Если не обращать внимание на изобилие родительных падежей или тем более слушать бегло, то фраза не замечается. Тут вспоминается анекдот про 40-ножку. Если она будет думать как ей передвигать ногами, то голова опухнет.